# how to display the groupname in android

Tags: android

Hi In the below how to get the group name based on json response from the server.how to display in listview.
New is the 1st position and
Group is the second position

**response**

```
{"groupname":"New"}{"groupname":"Group"}
```

**java**

```
 String groupdetails = imService.DispalyGroupDetails(imService.getUsername());
            try {

                JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(groupdetails);
                String[] groupname = new String[JA.length()];  
                for(int i=0;i<JA.length();i++)
                {
                    groupname[i] = JA.getJSONObject(i).getString("groupname");

                }  

            } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

this is php code Here I am getting the output like this

**updated**

```
case "DispalyGroupDetails":
    $userId = authenticateUser($db, $username, $password);

    if ($userId != NULL)

    {

        if (isset($_REQUEST['username']))           
        {               
             $username = $_REQUEST['username'];



             $sql = "select Id from users where username='$username' limit 1";

             if ($result = $db->query($sql))

             {
                    if ($row = $db->fetchObject($result))

                    {    

                                 $sql = "SELECT g.groupname 
                                        FROM `users` u, `friends` f, `group` g 
                                        WHERE u.Id=f.providerId and f.providerId=g.providerId
                                            GROUP BY g.id, g.groupname";
                                $theResult = $db->query($sql);

                                 if ($theResult) {

                    while( $theRow = $db->fetchObject($theResult))
                    { 
                    $json_output[]=$theRow;

                     print(json_encode($json_output));


                    }       
                            //$out = SUCCESSFUL;
                            } else {
                                    //$out = FAILED;
                            }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //$out = FAILED;                        
                    }
             }

             else
             {
                    //$out = FAILED;
             }              
        }

        else
        {
                //$out = FAILED;
        }           
    }
    else
    {
        //$out = FAILED;
    }   
break;
```

Comment: what issue you are getting?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK org.json.JSONException: Value {"groupname":"New"} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

Comment: same like that I wrote then also giving untermitnated

Comment: ["New","Group"]1 this output from server is it correct or wrong

Comment: why adding `1` with every response?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK this is output from server ["New","Group"]

Comment: {"groupname":"New"}{"groupname":"Group"} only this value got returning from server

Comment: but  `[{"groupname":"New"},{"groupname":"Group"}]` is valid JSONArray

Comment: can you see my php code

Comment: [{"groupname":"New"}][{"groupname":"New"},{"groupname":"Group"}] from server

Comment: still invalid string just return `[{"groupname":"New"},{"groupname":"Group"}]` from server

Comment: problem is in php code so you should do it your self

Answer (score 0):

```
{"groupname":"New"}{"groupname":"Group"}
```

First of all your response is not in proper JSON format. the response starts neither with JSONArray nor JSONObject. so firstly find a solution to get the response in proper JSON format on server side.

**Possible Option:** instead of parsing it with JSON try to do String operations on the response received from the server.

Comment: [{"groupname":"New"}][{"groupname":"New"},{"groupname":"Group"}] Now  I am getting the response like this

Comment: even this response that you posted in comments is not a valid JSON response. @tagore

Comment: http://www.thecave.info/output-json-header-in-php/ or http://stackoverflow.com/a/4064468/1576416 this answer might give you some hint on this